# Can I pass query parameters to the callback redirect URL in google ouath calendar api project setting?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

For the OAUTH setting for our google calendar project , the "REDIRECT URIS" is given as http://foo.com/calendar/callback

It is possible that when this callback is called we need some extra information passed in the callback.

For this what I planned was to pass in a key value param to the callback in the hope that it will be returned when the callback is invoked.

So when initiating the OAUTH process, for example set the redirect url as http://foo.com/calendar/callback?server_id=180

This is not working . Can anyone suggest an alternative approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems no. I create redirect cookie, send browser to OAuth, in callback method gets redirect cookie and make redirect to certain page.

Comment: "Seems no"? Not sure this answers the question.